How to catch one of many exceptions in the code and keep the original message?
I have an azure function that is currently listening to a topic in event hub.
We receive several json as events, and we need to implement a decorator to wrapp all the possible exceptions that can actually be raised during the execution ( transient errors, incoming payload errors ) and raise another event but keeping my first received message and the exception that was raised.
from fastapi import HTTPException
from pydantic import BaseModel
from dam_common.common import settings_helper
from enum import Enum
import json
import httpx
import logging


class EventHubRequest(BaseModel):
    IHDRequestID: str
    ProductType: str
    RequestType: str
    RequesterADGroupName: str
    TimeStamp: str


class RequestTypeValidation(Enum):
    IHD = "IHD"
    ANONYMIZED = "Anonymized"
    STUDY = "Keycoded"


async def main(eventHubMessage: str):
    try:
        # Deserialize the JSON payload
        data = json.loads(eventHubMessage)
        logging.info(f"Processing message: {data}")

        if isinstance(data, list):
            for record in data:
                validate_request(record)
                await process_request(record)
        else:
            validate_request(data)
            await process_request(data)

        logging.info("All requests processed successfully.")
    except json.JSONDecodeError:
        logging.error("Invalid JSON format in the request.")
    except ValueError as ve:
        logging.error(f"Validation error: {ve}")
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"An error occurred: {e}")


# Validate input fields in the request
def validate_request(data: dict):
    required_keys = [
        "RequestID",
        "ProductType",
        "RequestType",
        "RequesterADGroupName",
        "TimeStamp",
    ]
    for key in required_keys:
        if key not in data:
            raise ValueError(f"Missing required field: {key}")


async def process_request(data):
    logging.info(f"Processing request: {data}")

    # Convert the incoming data to EventHubRequest class type
    eventhub_request = EventHubRequest(
        IHDRequestID=data["RequestID"],
        ProductType=data["ProductType"],
        RequestType=data["RequestType"],
        RequesterADGroupName=data["RequesterADGroupName"],
        TimeStamp=data["TimeStamp"],
    )

    full_request = eventhub_request.dict()

    api_url = settings_helper.get_value("API_URL") + "access_manager/send_request_v2"
    headers = {
        "content-type": "application/json",
        "x-functions-key": settings_helper.get_value("MASTER_KEY"),
    }

    # Make the HTTP call
    async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
        try:
            logging.info(f"Sending request to `{api_url}` via httpx.")
            response = await client.post(
                api_url, json=full_request, headers=headers, timeout=60.0
            )
            response.raise_for_status()
            logging.info(f"Response status: {response.status_code}")
            logging.info(f"Response content: {response.text}")
        except httpx.HTTPStatusError as exc:
            logging.error(f"HTTP error occurred: {exc.response.text}")
            raise HTTPException(
                status_code=exc.response.status_code,
                detail="Failed to send request to access_manager",
            )
        except Exception as e:
            logging.error(f"Unexpected error sending request to access_manager: {e}")
            raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail="Unexpected error occurred.")


This is my code, I already tried to create a decorator but it looses the original message, I need to keep the message and send it to the decorator at the same time as the exception is raised... also bringing the exception message.
I expect to have a decorator wrapping and getting the exception among the og message every time an exception is raised in my code.

Can you make a minimal example of what you are trying to do? Your code is probably not runnable for me

Yes, thanks for answering:
This code is currently working fine, I just need to have a decorator that, for example, if the json.JSONDecodeError exceptions raises, captures the exception among my original eventHubMessage and send it to another method just to work there ( in any cases I need to send the message to a failure topic via event hub )

You could use raise HTTPException.. from e And use a custom exception handler:
from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException, Request
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse
import uvicorn
import logging

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
app = FastAPI()


@app.exception_handler(HTTPException)
async def unicorn_exception_handler(request: Request, exc: HTTPException):
    if exc.__cause__:
        logger.exception(exc)
    return JSONResponse(
        status_code=exc.status_code,
        content={"detail": exc.detail},
    )


@app.get("/")
def throw_error():
    try:
        raise ValueError("Whoops")
    except ValueError as e:
        raise HTTPException(detail="Something went wrong", status_code=500) from e


if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app)

Outputs:
C:\Users\tom.mclean\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\nemo-deploy-IXJNSscy-py3.11\Scripts\python.exe C:\Users\tom.mclean\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PyCharmCE2023.3\scratches\scratch.py 
INFO:     Started server process [22652]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
INFO:     Application startup complete.
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://127.0.0.1:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
INFO:     127.0.0.1:59028 - "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 Internal Server Error
ERROR:__main__:500: Something went wrong
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\tom.mclean\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PyCharmCE2023.3\scratches\scratch.py", line 24, in throw_error
    raise ValueError("Whoops")
ValueError: Whoops

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\tom.mclean\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\nemo-deploy-IXJNSscy-py3.11\Lib\site-packages\starlette\_exception_handler.py", line 42, in wrapped_app
    await app(scope, receive, sender)
  File "C:\Users\tom.mclean\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\nemo-deploy-IXJNSscy-py3.11\Lib\site-packages\starlette\routing.py", line 73, in app
    response = await f(request)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\tom.mclean\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\nemo-deploy-IXJNSscy-py3.11\Lib\site-packages\fastapi\routing.py", line 301, in app
    raw_response = await run_endpoint_function(
                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\tom.mclean\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\nemo-deploy-IXJNSscy-py3.11\Lib\site-packages\fastapi\routing.py", line 214, in run_endpoint_function
    return await run_in_threadpool(dependant.call, **values)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\tom.mclean\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\nemo-deploy-IXJNSscy-py3.11\Lib\site-packages\starlette\concurrency.py", line 39, in run_in_threadpool
    return await anyio.to_thread.run_sync(func, *args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\tom.mclean\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\nemo-deploy-IXJNSscy-py3.11\Lib\site-packages\anyio\to_thread.py", line 56, in run_sync
    return await get_async_backend().run_sync_in_worker_thread(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\tom.mclean\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\nemo-deploy-IXJNSscy-py3.11\Lib\site-packages\anyio\_backends\_asyncio.py", line 2441, in run_sync_in_worker_thread
    return await future
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\tom.mclean\AppData\Local\pypoetry\Cache\virtualenvs\nemo-deploy-IXJNSscy-py3.11\Lib\site-packages\anyio\_backends\_asyncio.py", line 943, in run
    result = context.run(func, *args)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\tom.mclean\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PyCharmCE2023.3\scratches\scratch.py", line 26, in throw_error
    raise HTTPException(detail="Something went wrong", status_code=500) from e
fastapi.exceptions.HTTPException: 500: Something went wrong


I never saw this, I just did a decorator with the help of chat gpt but it didnt work... because the wrap was preventing my valid inputs to pass...
